# Predicted values are not accurate

Tags: python, scikit-learn, time-series, arima

I am not able to get the Test Predictions Accurate at `print()`. Any help regarding proper way to predict using `Test.csv` will be appreciated.

```
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

x = df_log.values
y = df_test.values

train,test = x,y
flag = [i for i in train]
prediction = list()

for j in range(len(test)):
    model = ARMA(flag, order = (1,9))
    model_fit = model.fit()
    out = model_fit.forecast()
    y_hat = out[0]
    prediction.append(float(y_hat))
    observation_val = test[j]
    flag.append(observation_val)
    print('predicted_val =%f' % np.exp(y_hat), 'expected_val =%f' % observation_val)

err = mean_squared_error(test,prediction)
```

Comment: Please format your question and add the details of the question in the post instead of the title

Comment: Welcome to SO. I took the liberty to format your code so that it is more readable. I also changed your title. Can you please review this if I inferred your question correctly? If not, can you please specify what exactly you are seeing, what error you get (if any) and what you expect to happen?